# vNext middleware throws "Unable to locate suitable constructor for type 'XXX'" error

Tags: c#, middleware, asp.net-core

Trying to convert some OWIN middleware to vNext and getting the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to locate suitable
>   constructor for type 'MyMiddleware'.
>   Ensure the type is concrete and all parameters are accepted
>   by a constructor.    at
>   Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider
>   provider, Type instanceType, Obje ct[] parameters)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0(RequestDelegate
>   next)    at Microsoft.AspNet.Builder.ApplicationBuilder.Build()    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.HostingEngine.EnsureApplicationDelegate(HostingContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.HostingEngine.Start(HostingContext context)
>   at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Program.Main(String[] args)

I have no clue how to begin to debug this. I need to know what permutations the MS framework is attempting to call and using what parameters. How do I get it to spit this info out or set a break-point?

```
public class MyMiddleware : AuthenticationMiddleware<MyOptions>
{
     public MyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next,
        IOptions<MyOptions> options,
        ConfigureOptions<MyOptions> configureOptions)
        : base(next, options, configureOptions)
    {
           // doesn't want to call this
    }

    public MyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next,
        IOptions<MyOptions> options,
        ConfigureOptions<MyOptions> configureOptions,
        IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider,
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        : base(next, options, configureOptions)
        {
           // doesn't want to call this either and this is the one I'd like to be called
        }
}


public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddOptions();
        services.AddLogging();
        services.AddDataProtection();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseErrorPage();

        app.UseMyMiddleware(opts =>
        {
        });
    }
}


public static IApplicationBuilder UseMyMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder app, Action<MyMiddleware> configureOptions = null, string optionsName = "")
{
    return app.UseMiddleware<MyMiddleware>(
        new ConfigureOptions<MyMiddleware>(configureOptions ?? (o => { }))
        {
            Name = optionsName
        });
}
```

---

I've tried moving the parameters around in the constructor and also creating an overload with the minimal set of parameters for an `AuthenticationMiddleware` class but get the same error. Setting DNX_TRACE=1 provides no further insight into the problem either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to figure out how to get Visual Studio to break into MS framework code using these steps:

1. Go to `Debug -> Exception Settings`
2. Expand `Common Language Runtime Exceptions` and check the `InvalidOperationException`
3. Follow this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/02/06/debugging-asp-net-5-framework-code-using-visual-studio-2015.aspx) on how to debug framework code. (very cool 2015 feature)
4. In the above article instead of setting the `sources` to the physical location of the source code use the `projects` element instead. When you save `global.json` VS should refresh the Solution Explorer and add whatever framework projects it matched up to your solution. For me it was `Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection` & `Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.Interface`. Below is what my `global.json` looks like:

{
      "projects": [ "src", "test", "D:/GitHub/DependencyInjection/src" ], // note the use of forward slash instead of backslash, disappointing ;(
      "sources": ["packages"],
        "sdk": {
            "version": "1.0.0-beta4"
        }
    }

5. Next start the debugger on your project and it should compile not only your projects but whatever MS framework source code you downloaded from github thus producing the necessary framework .pdb's to allow you to break at the exception you were interested in from step 2.

---

After stepping through `ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance` code base I could see the problem. Copy/paste failure in my extension method. I was using `MyMiddleware` in the `Action<>` and `ConfigureOptions` parameters. Changing them to `MyOptions` fixed it.